# Shift-invariant symmetric functions in representation theory?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-functions

The connection between symmetric functions and representation theory is well-known.

Now consider the subspace of symmetric functions that are shift-invariant,
that is, functions satisfying $f(x+t+y+t,z+t,\dots,)=f(x,y,z,\dots)$ for all $t$.

A simple example of such a function is the square of the Vandermonde determinant.

Such functions appear naturally in physics, but my question is:
*do shift-invariant symmetric functions appear (naturally) in representation theory?*

Comment: This appears to be the ring of $S_n$-invariants on the symmetric algebra of the standard $n-1$-dimensional representation.

Comment: Is there some reference that treats this?

Comment: The permutation representation of $S_n$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ with basis $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. The symmetric algebra is the ring of symmetric functions in $n$-variables. The standard $n-1$ dimensional representation (call it $W$) is the subspace of $V$ with basis $x_i-x_{i+1}$. Now, $S(W)\subset S(V)$ consists of shift invariant symmetric functions.

Comment: They are also closely related to covariants of binary forms and therefore the representation theory of SL2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shift invariant symmetric functions are naturally identified with the characters of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{pgl}(n)$, the quotient of matrices by scalar matrices.  You could rightly point out that I have an isomorphism of Lie algebras $\mathfrak{pgl}(n)\cong \mathfrak{sl}(n)$ (the latter is trace 0 matrices), but if you think about the latter, you'll write down the wrong formulas.  For any representation of $\mathfrak{pgl}(n)$, the trace of the action of a matrix $A$ is a shift invariant symmetric function of its eigenvalues (since adding a constant to all the eigenvalues gives the same element of $\mathfrak{pgl}(n)$).  Any shift invariant symmetric function can be written as a sum of these characters, though not uniquely, since the vector representation has trivial character (which is a lesson in the difference between Lie algebras and groups!).

**EDIT**: To understand the relationship to special functions like Schur functions: one way to think about this is in terms of normalized variables $\tilde{x}_i=x_i-(x_1+\dots+x_n)/n$.  These are obviously shift invariant, and the shift invariant symmetric functions are just polynomials in the elementary symmetric functions of degree $\geq 2$ applied to this alphabet: $e_2(\tilde{\mathbf{x}}),e_3(\tilde{\mathbf{x}}), \dots$ (of course, $e_1(\tilde{\mathbf{x}})=0$).  The characters of simple $\mathfrak{pgl}(n)$ representations are just the Schur functions applied to $\tilde{\mathbf{x}}$.

Comment: Is there then a corresponding notion of Schur functions for these Lie algebras?